# Service Discovery Protocol: Check for multiple Services at once

Tags: c++, bluetooth, bluez

I followed the instructions on https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x604.html to check for a specified Bluetooth service of a device. I can succesfully check for the Serial Port Profile.

From Bluetooth traces, I noticed that some devices search for multiple services at the same time. Is it possible to extend the source code from the website mentioned above to get this functionality? I tried

```
[...]
search_list = sdp_list_append( NULL, &svc_uuid_1 );
search_list = sdp_list_append( NULL, &svc_uuid_2 );
[...]
```

but this seems not to work, it does not really 'append' the UUID in the `search_list` but does overwrite it.

Moreover, the traces show that one single SDP request does cover SPP, RFCOMM and L2CAP. Can profiles and protocols be mixed in SDP request?

Additionally, I'm confused by the following snippet, also from website above:

```
// specify that we want a list of all the matching applications' attributes
uint32_t range = 0x0000ffff;
attrid_list = sdp_list_append( NULL, &range );
```

What exactly is `range`? What options does it offer? Unfortunately, I couldn't find any explanations in Bluetooth core documentation v4.2.